# Which one is correct definition in the phrase?

Tags: grammar, word-meaning

There is an exemple of phrase below.

> With great attention to detail.

And there are two definiton on preposition of 'to'.

1) reaching a particular state.
2) to show the person or thing that is affected by an action.

Which one is correct definition?
[enter link description here](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/to_1?q=to)

Comment: What is the source of your two defintions?

Comment: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/to_1?q=to

Comment: That site lists **18** definitions of *to*, not only two. Why are you ignoring all of the others? I'm inclined to think the most appropriate definition is 11: "directed towards; concerning," as in "she made a reference to her recent book."

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But do you really think that the most suitable definition is 11? Could you go into more detail about that?